# Red Pitaya questions

Tags: oscilloscope, redpitaya

Today I had a question from my kid as to what the hell can she do with this red thingie on my desk. I showed a IC 555 flip flop and its output on the screen, all I got is a so what?

A request for the Red Pitaya team ( I am no teacher) is can someone put together a set of things that can pique the interest of a 11 year old? Need some great show case to get them to see the unseen?

What are the things to show them on the oscilloscope? What kind of spectrum analysis would be the first thing to do?

The Quick start provides inputs as to what can be done for it to be up and running? Then what?

A section or some great inputs here are wonderful.

Answer (score 4):

Try a nice piece of wire and a nearby AM radio station (535-1605 kHz).
You could even try to tune in to the same station with a household radio and see/hear how the sidebands shake up and down in tune with the broadcast.
Made for a great chat with my two 5yo and 7yo assistants. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Showing the output of the 555 with the Spectrum Analyser would show that a square wave has many odd harmonics.

Changing the frequency of the 555 will show on the Spectrum Analyser and Oscilloscope.

Answer (score 0):

Get two Utrasonic transducers, use one with the generator and one on the scope.
You can show tuning the frequency, directional capabilities, obstructions etc., and all with sound that we can't hear.
I just did it and it's quite (and quiet) fun!